# Item Reader for a Map in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a simple `HashMap`, and it seems like there's no way to pass it to any standard `ItemReader` from Spring Batch which I find quite frustrating. Will I have to write my own Item Reader in order to process a `HashMap` or is there something that I'm missing ?

Comment: How you get the HashMap?

Comment: Basically another component is invoked which returns HashMap. So at that point I'm stuck with it, and need to pass to the Item Reader.

Comment: Is there any xml or java code you can show ?

Answer (score 6):

Well it depends on what your items are: keys, values or entries of your map.

You can use the `ListItemReader` and pass keys, values or entries as a list in its constructor. For example:

```
Map<Integer, String> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put(1, "foo");
items.put(2, "bar");

ListItemReader<Integer> keysItemReader = new ListItemReader<>(new ArrayList<>(items.keySet()));
ListItemReader<String> valuesItemReader = new ListItemReader<>(new ArrayList<>(items.values()));
ListItemReader<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entriesItemReader = new ListItemReader<>(new ArrayList<>(items.entrySet()));
```

You can also use the `IteratorItemReader` and pass the iterator on your items to it in the constructor:

```
IteratorItemReader<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iteratorItemReader = new IteratorItemReader<>(items.entrySet().iterator());
// same for keys or values
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no MapReader in spring batch. What we have done in our projects is to create common-batch module to have those additional utility readers and writer missing from Spring Batch core components.
That would be the be the best and good reusable way across applications.